# How to prevent an image with extra bottom text from shifting up in flexbox thumbnail

Tags: css

Bottom text of the image is shifting the image up in the list of thumbnails.

I saw some link about Mozilla firefox shifting images up and the solution is given was to use

```
vertical-align: top;
```

or

```
vertical-align: bottom;
```

The problem was half solved as the text is extending beyond its normal height to another image below it instead of pushing the image down to maintain a general form.

## Here is my CSS code

```
  .flex-cover{
   width:100%; 
   display:flex; 
   justify-content: center;
  }
  .flex-child{
    text-align: center;
  }
  .flex-head{
     font-size: 20px;
     margin-top: 10px; 
     color: #ce7842; 
     text-shadow: #aaa 0 0 1px; 
     font-weight: bold;
     padding:10px;
     text-align: center;
  }

  .flex-body{
     color:#969c84;
  }

  .flex-box{
     display: inline-block;
     width:140px;
     height:140px; 
     margin:10px; 
     vertical-align: top;
     text-align: center;
  }

  .flex-pics{
    height:120px;
    width:100%;
  }

  .flex-box .flex-pics{
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
```

## Here is the html code

```
<div class="flex-cover">

    <div class="flex-child">

      <div class="flex-head"> Recent Articles</div>

      <div class="flex-body">
        <div class="mycover flex-box">
        <div class="pull-left flex-pics" style="background-image: url(&quot;/images/im/imm20.jpg&quot;);"></div><br>       
         My Article 1
        </div> 

        <div class="mycover flex-box">
        <div class="pull-left flex-pics" style="background-image: url(&quot;/images/im/imm20.jpg&quot;);"></div><br>       
         My Article 2 with some more content added to it
        </div>

        <div class="mycover flex-box">
        <div class="pull-left flex-pics" style="background-image: url(&quot;/images/im/imm20.jpg&quot;);"></div><br>       
          My Article 2
        </div>

        <div class="mycover flex-box">
        <div class="pull-left flex-pics" style="background-image: url(&quot;/images/im/imm20.jpg&quot;);"></div><br>       
          My Article 4
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

**Original View When Browser Not Folded**

[image: Original View When Browser Not Folded]

**Image After Browser was folded**

[image: Image After Browser was folded]

As you can see, some text is going under instead of pushing the image down. I also do not want to use:

`float:left`

because it seems impossible to shift the image to center when the float is used. So, a good answer will be duly awarded. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: your flex boxes have a fixed height from 140px. you should check that

Comment: Also, you should use *actual* inline images and not background images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the `height: 140px;` for .flex-box. That's why it happens.